# How to avoid for loops and let statement for this program

Tags: rust

In Rust, how do I avoid writing for loops and let statement? This program is used to record which line of text the string appears on and the position it appears on the line.

I know I can use iterators and map to eliminate them, but I just contacted Rust, I don't know how to write it.

```
pub struct L{
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}
pub fn foo (text: &str, string: &str)->Vec<L> {
    let mut r= Vec::new();
    let mut x=0;
    for line in text.lines(){
        for (y, _) in line.match_indices(string){
            r.push(L{
                    x : x,
                    y: y, })
        }
        x+=1;
    }
    r
}
```

Comment: Before you go modifying it to use iterator chains, consider whether that is an improvement (unless this is just a mental exercise, in which case go nuts). There's no indexing in the loop to remove unnecessary bounds checks from, it's not possible to pre-allocate the vector with the correct size, and the nested `for` loop is pretty readable. I could see this one going either way, so if you find the imperative version easier to understand, don't feel like you have to change it. Some people go overboard with making everything functional and forget that Rust is imperative at heart ;-)

Comment: @trentcl: I agree totally. That said, I would add at least the `enumerate()` call to avoid the mutable `x` and the increment: that for me is an absolute gain. The `flat_map`... meh.

Comment: Ok, fair point. `enumerate()` is all win, I agree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the equivalent using iterators:

```
pub fn foo(text: &str, string: &str) -> Vec<L> {
    text.lines()
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(x, line)| {
            line.match_indices(string).map(move |(y, _)| { L { x, y } })
        })
        .collect()
}
```

Broken down line for line:

```
.enumerate()
```

[`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) is used to transform an iterator of `T` into an iterator of `(usize, T)`, basically zipping the original value with the index. You do this because you are keeping track of the line number with `x`.

```
.flat_map(|(x, line)| { ... })
```

[`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) is used to allow each value in the iterator to return its own iterator whose values are then flattened into one stream.

```
line.match_indices(string).map(move |(y, _)| { L { x, y } })
```

Here we're simply using [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) to take the `x` and the `y` and create an `L`. `move` is used because otherwise `x` will be *borrowed* for the closure, but the iterator and closure are returned to the `flat_map` closure, living longer than `x`. The `move` is just copying the `x` so its not an issue.

```
.collect()
```

[`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) is used to convert an iterator into something that can be made from the iterator by implementing `FromIterator`, usually collections like `Vec`. This is also using type-inferencing by knowing that we're returning a `Vec<L>`, it knows to collect into a `Vec<L>`.

---

You can verify the equivalence on the [`Rust Playground`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50770573b0e087546bc6a1d8cdc3200e).

Comment: Well, I beat you by 5 minutes with identical code and a decent explanation.... :)

Comment: It is nice to be validated by other answers. :) Though I'm not surprised; these iterator patterns and solutions have become fairly normalized even across languages (some just use different terminology).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you provided converted to use iterators:

```rust
pub fn foo(text: &str, string: &str) -> Vec<L> {
  text
    .lines()
    // Allows us to get the current count *and* the element during iteration
    .enumerate()
    // flatten the inner iterator into one single iterator
    .flat_map(|(index, line)| {
      line
        .match_indices(string)
        // the inner iterator
        .map(move |(y, _)| L { x: index, y: y })
    })
    // collect the iterator into a `Vec` of `L`
    .collect::<Vec<L>>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try like this: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abc26d1e6449b80ac42e455ec2143ef9)

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct L {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}

pub fn foo (text: &str, string: &str) -> Vec<L> {
    text.lines()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(x, line)| 
            line.match_indices(string)
                .map(move |(y, _)| L{x, y}))
        .flatten()
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo(
            "aaa bbb ccc\nbbb aaa ccc\nccc aaa bbb", 
            "bbb"))
    // [L { x: 0, y: 4 }, L { x: 1, y: 0 }, L { x: 2, y: 8 }]
}
```